# Delete all apps that match a filter

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is there a quick way to do something like:

`cf delete *-failed`

To delete all applications ending with `-failed` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're on Linux/Unix/Cygwin, you can do this:

```
cf apps | tail +5 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | grep "my-filter" | xargs -n 1 cf delete -f
```

The first will get a list of apps, the second will strip off the headers that the cf cli writes, the third cuts out just the app names and the fourth filters and the fifth will run `cf delete -f` for each app it finds.

There are tons of variations on this, to filter and grab only the information you want.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks this is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Write a shell-script or Powershell script (Wrapper scripts) that execute this command

> cf apps

and read the response that is given back.. You will get all the app-names . Read that list recursively and Match the pattern for app-names ending with **-failed** and then execute delete-command

> cf delete APP_NAME

Comment: Yes that's what I've imagined doing first but I was wondering if there was any quicker way. Thank you anyway !